# Find a regular expression for combination of string and substring

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an string say 
string="eg=abc." or  "eg2= abc " or eg2=" abc." or eg2="abc"

Now I have another string say 
substring = " abc." or " abc " or "abc. "  or "abc"

Now I want to return true when string and substring is any of the following combination. 
Question is how to do that using regex.

Comment: "If all you have is a regex, every string looks like a problem." *--CodeGnome's Law of Fixed-String Matching*

Comment: This is really vague. Are they arrays or just examples? You want a true value when any of the substrings are part of any of the strings?

Comment: "any of the following combination" -- what combination?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Regexp`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Regexp.html) along with match to easily search strings:

```
str1 = "abc=def="
str2 = "abc"
!! str1.match(Regexp.compile(Regexp.escape(str2))) #=> true
!! str1.match(Regexp.compile(Regexp.escape("12"))) #=> false
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have the strings in arrays:

```
strs = ["eg=abc.", "eg2= abc ", 'eg2=" abc."', 'eg2="abc"']
subs = [" abc.", " abc ", "abc. ", "abc"]
```

Then you can do the following:

```
strs.any?{|s| subs.any?{|sub| s.include? sub}}
```

This takes advantage of `Enumerable#any?` and `String#include?` for brevity.

But i can't help thinking there's another way to solve your problem, if we knew a little bit more about what you're really trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

### No Regex Needed: Just Use String#include? Method

You can check a check without regular expressions with the [String#include?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-include-3F) method. For example:

```
# True if str1 contains str2; otherwise false.
def string_match? str1, str2
    str1.include? str2
end

# Your provided corpus, as a pair of arrays.
str1 = ["eg=abc.", "eg2= abc ", 'eg2=" abc."', 'eg2="abc"']
str2 = [" abc.", " abc ", "abc. ", "abc"]

# Putting the method to use on your sample strings.    
str1.each do |str1|
  str2.each do |str2|
  puts "'#{str1}' includes '#{str2}'" if string_match?(str1, str2)
  end
end
```

This just checks each string in the first array against each string in the second array, and reports a match. Given any two strings, *#string_match?* will return true if the substring is found, and false otherwise.